# Neo4j SDN4 repository method with custom query and composite entity

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have the following SDN 4 entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision {


    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Decision> parentDecisions;

...
}
```

I'd like to find this entity by id and return all its `parentDecisions` with a following SDN4 repository method and the custom Cypher query:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE d.id = {decisionId} OPTIONAL MATCH (d)<-[rdp:CONTAINS]-(parentD:Decision) RETURN d, rdp, parentD
Decision getById(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId);
```

right now in case of existing `parentD` it fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Result not of expected size. Expected 1 row but found 3
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.queryForObject(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.queryForObject(Neo4jSession.java:382)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

How to properly implement this logic with SDN4 repository method and the custom Cypher query ?

**UPDATED**

I tested approach suggested by **frant.hartm**. Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

For example the following SDN4 repository method correctly returns 2 `Decision`:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision)-[drd:FOLLOWS]->(following:Decision) WHERE d.id = {decisionId} RETURN following")
List<Decision> test(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId);
```

but the next one:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE d.id = {decisionId} OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[rdf:FOLLOWS]->(followD:Decision) RETURN d as decision, collect(rdf), collect(followD) ")
DecisionHolder test1(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId);
```

returns only main `decision` (`holder.getDecision()`) but with empty collection of `followD` (`holder.getDecision().getFollowDecisions()`) Decision.

This is `Decision` entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision {

    private static final String FOLLOWS = "FOLLOWS";

    @Relationship(type = FOLLOWS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Decision> followDecisions;

    @Relationship(type = FOLLOWS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    public Set<Decision> getFollowDecisions() {
        return followDecisions;
    }

    @Relationship(type = FOLLOWS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    public void setFollowDecisions(Set<Decision> followDecisions) {
        this.followDecisions = followDecisions;
    }

....

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I never used SDN 4, but I believe the problem is that the method `getById` expect 1 row as return and you are returning 3 because the passed `{decisionId}` has 3 parents. This way your query is returning the cartesian product between `d` (1 node) and `parentD` (3 nodes). 3x1=3 rows returned. One possible workaround is change your custom query to `MATCH (d:Decision)
WHERE d.id = {decisionId}
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)<-[rdp:CONTAINS]-(parentD:Decision)
RETURN d, collect(rdp), collect(parentD)
`. That is: `collect()` `rdp` and `partendD` when returning.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately doesn't work with the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core issue is that your query returns multiple `Decision` instances (under different variables - `d` and `parentD`), so it can't just arbitrarily chose one. Use `@QueryResult` to extract desired value. Also use `COLLECT` to get a single result.

```
@QueryResult
public class DecisionHolder {
    Decision d;
}

MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE d.id = {decisionId} " + 
    "OPTIONAL MATCH (d)<-[rdp:CONTAINS]-(parentD:Decision) " +
    "RETURN d, collect(rdp), collect(parentD)")
DecisionHolder getById(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId);
```

**Update:**

For the relationships to map correctly relationship entities and simple relationships with same type must not be mixed.

If you have a simple relationship and relationship entity with same type

- when they represent same relationship type use relationship entity class in your relationship definition (e.g. `Set<ParentDecisionRelationship> parentDecisions`)
- when they represent different types rename one of them

Comment: Thanks for your answser but unfortunately it doesn't work. Please see my updated question for details.

Comment: Plese check out https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-sdn-ogm-issue-report-template/blob/so-46324712/so-46324712/src/test/java/org/neo4j/sdn/test/SdnTestCase.java#L55 to see it working as I described. There must be something more. Are you able to create/share a test case?